# Sass and first element

Tags: html, css, sass

Now I have html:

```
<div class="box">
   <span class="title">first</span>
   <span>second</span>
   <span>third</span>
   <span>fourth</span>
</div>
```

And Sass:

```
.box {
    background-color: gray;
    span {
       margin: 10px;
       &.title {
          color: red;
       }
    }
}
```

I would like to remove class `.title` and replace `&.title` with a any selector.

Is it possible without class in first element? I would like to in HTML simply:

```
<div class="box">
   <span>first</span>
   <span>second</span>
   <span>third</span>
   <span>fourth</span>
</div>
```

And first span have to has red color.

Comment: or just look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/2309928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that's possible event without sass have a loook at:

> [pseudo-selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

`:first-of-type` or `:first-child`